# Query postmeta values, and return multiple post_titles for common meta value

Tags: custom-field, search, post-meta, wpdb

As of now I query the DB:

```
global $wpdb;

        $query = $wpdb->prepare('
            SELECT p.post_id, p.meta_value, pm.post_title
            FROM %1$s AS p
            JOIN %2$s AS pm ON (p.post_id = pm.ID)
            WHERE p.meta_key = "Price"',

            $wpdb->postmeta,
            $wpdb->posts
        );
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

This returns an array of objects containing the metavalue, post_id, and post_title. Using these I create my dropdown of "prices"

```
<select name="s">
    <?php

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        echo "<option value=\"$result->post_title\">$result->meta_value</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

However, as of now this generates a selection for each value with no regard to weather it is a duplicate or not. For instance if price is "10" on two separate posts, I will have 10 twice in my dropdown. How can I alter this so that there is only 1 "10" and it returns all the posts with metavalue of 10?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You want to "return all the posts with metavalue of 10" how, exactly? Do you want whatever script is called by the form that contains the dropdown to do that?

Comment: `searchform.php` contains the dropdown in the form that GET's "/". The dropdown should list all the price values. The result from `search.php` should query the price values, and finally return post titles.